# ajax textBox-watermark issue with Extenders (MaskEdit + Validator) - set a custom default vlaue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

i am trying to set a default value for that "TBXinsertDate" `asp:TextBox` control,
by using the `focus` event (`js`) , though... seems to me that the `ajax watermark Extender`
actually **overrides my action** with it's own , if that's the issue ,

**How could i set a default value of my own ?**

**`aspx`**

```aspx
<cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender  ID="insertDate_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TBXinsertDate" WatermarkText="insertDate" WatermarkCssClass="WaterMarkedTextBox">
</cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

<cc1:MaskedEditExtender enabled="true" MaskType="Date" ID="insertDate_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="tet"
                                TargetControlID="TBXinsertDate"  InputDirection="LeftToRight"  CultureName="en-GB" 
                                UserDateFormat="None" Mask="99/99/9999" MessageValidatorTip="true"  OnFocusCssClass="maskedFocus" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" ErrorTooltipCssClass="toolTipForInvalid">
</cc1:MaskedEditExtender>

<asp:TextBox ID="TBXinsertDate" runat="server" ToolTip="please insert date" Width="76px">
                        </asp:TextBox>
```

and I know, I could use datePicker ... of any kind , but the requirements are as in question , set it manually via keyboard.

**update**

default should be todays datem,like...26/12/2012

**Update #2** Code

below is : Javascript+Ajax dual Mode WaterMark

**Update3** and Most ***important one*** :

1) not **this Js code** is the special thing about my problem ... it's not even the source of it

2) the problem does not exist if I omit the Ajax Extenders : `validation` + `maskEdit`
from the ASPX !

3) to summaries it , the problem is to set default value = today date

and if i do not add that Extenders - `validator` + `Maskedit` 
my tries are working  fine !! value is set .

### could someone with experience on `Ajax Toolkit`,  give a little help here please.

i will also update the title of this question

```js
    var masked = "__/__/____";
    var MultiWatermark = function (obj, options) {

        var defaultOptions = {
            // These variables can be changed to alter functionality using the passed in options object
            watermarkVals: ["insert date", "mmddyyyy"], // all watermark values.
            totalIterations: 20, // how many times to go through watermark Array.
            watermarkClassName: "WaterMarkedTextBox",
            normalClassName: "NormalTextBox",
            changeDelay: 1000, // in milliseconds
            extraValsToCheck: ['', null]// 
        }

        //merge options with defaultOptions
        for (var property in defaultOptions) {
            if (!options.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                options[property] = defaultOptions[property];
            }
        }

        // local variables (do not change)
        var textBox = obj;
        var iterationCounter = 0;
        var itemCounter = 0;
        var intrId;

        var startWatermark = function () {
            itemCounter = 0; iterationCounter = 0; // resets for after blur
            intrId = setInterval(function () { alterWaterMark() }, options.changeDelay);
        }

        var stopWatermark = function () {
            clearInterval(intrId);
        }

        var alterWaterMark = function () {

            if (iterationCounter < options.totalIterations) {

                textBox.value = options.watermarkVals[itemCounter];
                itemCounter += 1;
                if (itemCounter == options.watermarkVals.length) {
                    itemCounter = 0;
                    iterationCounter += 1;
                }

            }
            else {
                stopWatermark();
            }

        }

        var isWatermarkValue = function (val) {

            var i = options.watermarkVals.length;
            while (i--) {
                if (options.watermarkVals[i] === val) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            // value is not in watermark array, so check secondary values.
            i = options.extraValsToCheck.length;
            while (i--) {
                if (options.extraValsToCheck[i] === val) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        var setClass = function () {
            textBox.className = isWatermarkValue(textBox.value) ? options.watermarkClassName : options.normalClassName;

          ///////this is wher i tried to set it <==========
            textBox.value = "26/12/2012";
        }

        var focusEvent = function () {

            stopWatermark();
            if (isWatermarkValue(textBox.value)) {
                textBox.value = "";

          ///////this is where  i was First time  trying to set it <==========

                //alert("was focused");
            }
            setClass()
        }

        var blurEvent = function () {

            if (isWatermarkValue(textBox.value)) {
                startWatermark();
            }
            setClass();

        }

        var initWatermark = function () {
            setClass();
            textBox.onfocus = focusEvent;
            textBox.onblur = blurEvent;
            startWatermark();
        }


        initWatermark();
    }


    function runWatermarkOn(formId, targetid, wm1,wm2,wm3, iterations, delay) {

        var dateOptions = {
            // These variables alter functionality, the main script will use the defaults of any options not included here 
            watermarkVals: [wm1, wm2], // all watermark values.
            totalIterations: iterations,
            changeDelay: delay, // in milliseconds
            extraValsToCheck: ['', null, masked]
        }
        if (wm3!= undefined)
            dateOptions.watermarkVals[2] = arguments[4];
        new MultiWatermark(document.forms[formId].elements[targetid], dateOptions);

    }
    runWatermarkOn("form1", "TBXinsertDate", "insert Date", "dd/mm/yyyy", undefined, 2, 1500);
```

please See Comment in middle of Code block above . that's where i was trying it.
tried hardcoding todays date as it's value.
and as i was refering to the problem . the idea is that it does not matter what javascript or Jquery I am trying to use , as the MaskEditExtender over riding my value.

i will really appreciate some help here .

thanks

Comment: Where's the JavaScript? What kind of default value are you trying to set? And why *only* on focus?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud it is a dual water mark script my idea (: 
i will be happy to share it , though it's little long code if you dont mind me post that

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud i have updated my question . now it **does** work - setting the value in my code does apply , **BUT** , only if i do not add that Ajax `MaskEdit` + `muskEditValidators` = so this is the problem . now could you tell what is it michael ?

Comment: Try setting value like $find("behTBXinsertDate" ).set_Text("26/12/2012"); as beh is being added by AjaxToolkit to your textbox control for control behavior.

Comment: @vendettamit thanks,  i tried every combination, **BUT** -i thought of an idea: 1) set initial value: `enabled = false ` for the `MaskEditExtender`.(C#),  then 2) the Date-Default-value (set via C# onload, will just simply apply!).  and Then 3)`focusevent` = `extender`**.**`Enabeld = true`, any idea ?  . initial value will then be allready set , then set the focus to target extender so it will set it's enabled to trued ! can u help on the js focus part to set `Enabled` = `true` ? (i know it c#) `insertDate_MaskedEditExtender.Enabled = false;` (this is onload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved By me , as usuall when the question has too long code to read through

although the code was not the issue but as i said , it is the Extender - MaskEdit that is overriding my values .

as a workaround what i have done , is C#
onload disable that MaskEdit

```
    insertDate_MaskedEditExtender.Enabled = false;
```

and javascript

```
var MaskEdit1 = $('#BEHAVIOR-id' (not the standart one of the extender);
MaskEdit1.disabled = false;
```